# Change button title issue

Tags: java, gwt

Hi I use GWT and I have a com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Button that has the following eventHandler:

```
        Button viewCommentsButton = new Button("View ");
        viewCommentsButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if (!childrenVisible) {
                    addChildren();
                    getParent().setTitle("Close");
                } else {
                    removeChildren();
                    getParent().setTitle("View");
                }
            }

        });
```

As you can see I tried getParent().setTitle() method but with no effect. The if works fine so I guess I can't get the reference to my button object but the code compiles and getParent returns a widget so most likely my button.

However, the addChildren and removeChildren methods are working properly but my button has the initial title all the time. Any ideas why? Hope this makes sense.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to set the title on `viewCommentsButton`, call `viewCommentsButton.setTitle()`.

If you are trying to set the text in the button, call `viewCommentsButton.setText()`.

For either of these you'll have to mark the button as final - declare it with `final Button viewCommentsButton = ...`

The context of `getParent()` is confusing.  `getParent()`, the way you're using it, will return the parent of the widget in which you're defining all of this, NOT the parent of `viewCommentsButton` and definitely not `viewCommentsButton` itself.

Comment: I will accept this in 7 minutes. I had this option to begin with but then I had to declare the variable either globaly or final and I thought about giving it a shot. +1

Answer (score 2):

Make your button a class variable, rather than a method variable and than you would be able to use it (refer it) inside the click handler.

For example:

```
viewCommentsButton = new Button("View "); //viewCommentButton is the private member.
    viewCommentsButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if (!childrenVisible) {
                addChildren();
                viewCommentButton.setTitle("Close");
                viewCommentButton.setText("Close");
            } else {
                removeChildren();
                viewCommentButton.setTitle("View");
                viewCommentButton.setText("View");
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: +1 You are right, although my main concern was if getParent() gets me the reference to my button or not.

Comment: I guess as some mentioned, it refers to the parent widget, which usually are panes or layputs, not a button.

Answer (score 1):

You should use setText

setTitle is the "tooltip"

Comment: I don't have the setText method for my button oject.

Comment: Strange http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html documents it

Comment: You are right. But I used com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Button and not com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button they are slightly different. +1 for trying to help nevertheless.